# How to override rate.php in magento enterprise or magento 1.8?

Tags: magento

I need to change app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate.php

```
if (!is_numeric($this->getRate()) || $this->getRate() <= 0) {
```

**to**

```
if (!is_numeric($this->getRate()) || $this->getRate() < 0) {
```

So I want to override this file in stead of changing in core folder.

Please help....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to rewrite core Magento model in config.xml file of your custom module:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyPackage_MyModule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </MyPackage_MyModule>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <mypackage_mymodule>
                <class>MyPackage_MyModule_Model</class>
            </mypackage_mymodule>
            <tax>
                <rewrite>
               <calculation_rate>MyPackage_MyModule_Model_Calculation_Rate</calculation_rate>  
                </rewrite>
            </tax>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Than you need to create new Rate.php file here: MyPackage/MyModule/Model/Calculation/Rate.php and extend the core Magento Tax Rate model. At the end you should add the method you need. You can test if rewrite was successful like this:

```
class MyPackage_MyModule_Model_Calculation_Rate extends Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation_Rate {

     /**
     * Prepare location settings and tax postcode before save rate
     *
     * @return Mage_Tax_Model_Calculation_Rate
     */

    protected function _beforeSave()
    { 
        die("it works!");
    }
}
```

Now, when your new method works, you can add code you wish.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks J.S. for your help.
I tried the same yesterday night, and it works. :) :)

could you tell me what if i add _beforeSave() method only, and rest of methods remain same.

Comment: You can add only methods you need. If you don't have all methods in your rewrited model, Magento will search for that methods in core file :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add your own file Rate.php to your folder `./app/code/local/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation/Rate.php`

Magento will check this folders if files are exist and prioritize them before loads from core, this means file `./app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation/Rate.php` file will not be loaded.

legend:

```
ROOT/app/core/ magento files (never do any changes)    
ROOT/app/community/ installed modules etc ...   
ROOT/app/local/ your own changes only for this installation
```

Comment: +1 for the other perspective. Magento's framework is so featured and complex that it's good to have all the options on the table when tackling a task.